# ggplot2 geom_density_2d allows to fill by factors but not by values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use stat_density2D function but coloring the densities by the values of the points. I can color the densities by factors, but not by continous values.

```
plot_data <-
  data.frame(X = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)),
             Y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
             Label = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 150)),
             Continous = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(X, Y)) + 
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", aes(alpha = ..level.., fill = Label))
```

Obtaining the plot coloured by label:
[ColorByLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNflh.png)

but if we `aes(alpha = ..level.., fill = Continous)` change we obtain:
[ColorByContinous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmPDV.png)

Comment: What would the desired result be? The densities in your first example are first grouped by `Label` and then estimated separately. How do you imagine this working with a continuous variable?

Comment: OP, what you're asking really isn't too possible when you think of it.  If I picked two different colors... how in the world would you be able to identify a particular color that was in the middle between those two colors and *also* consider the alpha value?  It's possible only if you "slice" up the data into discrete sections.  That's why it will display correctly colors if you color by `Label` (which is discrete) vs. color by `Continuous`, (which is numeric).

Comment: `stat_density_2d` gives the density of x and y. What do you want displayed from your Continuous data? The actual (use geom_point); or maybe the mean or other function of the data - then see `stat_summary_2d(fun = ` for example:  `ggplot(plot_data, aes(X, Y, z= Continous, color=Label)) +  stat_summary_2d(fun = function(x) sum(x^2))`

Comment: @chemdork123 - about the coloring, just creating a gradient from color1 to color2, I just want that the color of the densities depends on the values of the continuous value on these points

Comment: @M.Viking - I wanted to see if we can create a gradient derived from the 'z' values on the points. Like creating a topographic map from these data.

Comment: @GuiSeSa how would the gradient be calculated when there are multiple Z - for example, in the center and the edges of the A Label range, there are points valued between -4 to 12 and Z value, `ggplot(plot_data %>% filter(Label=="A")) + geom_point(aes(X, Y, color=Continous))`....  Assuming you want 'mean' of local points, i think `geom_hex` is going to be the answer `ggplot(plot_data, aes(X, Y, z= Continous, color=Label)) +  stat_summary_hex(fun = function(z) mean(z), alpha =0.75)`